# Test in Dalekjs doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, dalekjs

I tried this code to test if in Dalekjs Documentation , assertions examples are corrects but it doesn't work in Chrome. And it expected that it runs in Chrome and not in Firefox!? Did i do something wrong or it's just an old example.
Thx for help !

```js
module.exports = {
'MDE does its thing': function (test) {
  test
    .open('http://dalekjs.com/guineapig/')
    .assert.dialogText().is.not('I am an prompt', 'Exterminate!')
  .screenshot('test.png')
  .done();

   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the string should be 'I am a prompt':

```
.assert.dialogText().is.not('I am a prompt', 'Exterminate!')
```